# Add a custom field to a custom form

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, custom-list, custom-form

I have created a custom form for displaying items in our sharepoint 2013 list.
Now when I add a custom column (field) for the list, the item is not being added to the custom form.
1. Why?
2. Is it possible to add fields to the custom form without using the sharepoint designer. I expected such feature within sharepoint list/field settings.

Comment: are you customize all items form or display form ? should you provide more details and steps that you do

Comment: If it is custom form, then you will need designer to add new column in form, it will not get auto added. for more info refer: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/43160/how-to-add-data-field-to-existing-custom-list-form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List form view is consisting of xslt web part and like any of these xslt webparts they too are static and don't refresh automatically.

If you so desire to have auto updating custom form, you will need to custom code it.